# Can I run two 4k (3840x2160) displays at 60hz on a Macbook Pro 13" 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I think the title says it all. Can I run two 4k (3840x2160) displays, both at 60hz on a Macbook Pro 13' 2015? I understand they might need to be SST and each connected to a Thunderbolt 2 port. But I cannot get a confirmation whether that setup would work.

https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719?locale=en_US says:

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on up to two external displays, both at millions of colors.
>   …
>   Support for up to 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz on a single external display (model with AMD Radeon R9 M370X only)

Unfortunately, it does not state at what **frequency** the two displays can be run.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587 says:

> With OS X Yosemite v10.10.3 and later, most single-stream 4K (3840x2160) > displays are supported at 60Hz operation on the following Mac computers: … MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) and later. MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) and later

Unfortunately it does not state whether **two** displays can be run at 3840 by 2160 at 60hz

Comment: I also posted this question at the Apple Support Community: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7802640

Comment: @Tetsujin : I wonder why this question was marked as a duplicate. This question is 1 year, 8 months old. The other question "MacBook Pro - how many displays, what resolution/frequency?" is only 1 month old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are using an [Early 2015 MacBook Pro 13"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204349), it uses the Intel Iris 6100 chip.

From the review of the Intel Iris 6100 by [NotebookCheck](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Iris-Graphics-6100.125591.0.html):

> All Broadwell GPUs support OpenCL 2.0 and DirectX 12 (FL 11_1). The video engine can now decode H.265 using both fixed function hardware as well as available GPU shaders. Up to three displays can be connected via DP 1.2/eDP 1.3 (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz) or HDMI 1.4a (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 24 Hz). HDMI 2.0, however, is not supported.

**The capability is there to support up to 3 displays with a max resolution of 3840x2160 @ 60Hz.**

You connect it via mDP (mini Display Port) through the Thunderbolt 2 port.

Comment: Hey Allan! Thanks a bunch, that is the most substantial answer that I received so far (incl. Apple Support) :) I did read the writeup on the Intel Iris 6100. I just wonder whether the Thunderbolt 2 bus (Does such thing exist?) can handle the load. So far, I do not even know if the two Thunderbolt 2 ports are on the same or on two different busses.

Comment: No problem.  The TB2 bus (which exists) won't apply here.  It's the DisplayPort signal that will apply.  The DispayPort signals exist alongside the PCIe signals on the [Thunderbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)) bus.  So, it has more than enough bandwidth.

Comment: Great! Thanks again. I accepted the answer. It will take .5year until I can plug the devices together and report first hand.

Comment: I can confirm that it does, I am running 2 displays at 3840 x 2160 @ 60Hz on my Early 2015 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can:

[image: Screenshot confirming MacBook Pro driving 2 Asus MG28U monitors at 3840x2160]
[image: Screenshot confirming MacBook Pro model (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015, Intel Iris 6100 with 1536 MB of VRAM)]

It's even at 60Hz, and supports HiDPI scaling:

[image: Screenshot showing off support of HiDPI scaling]

Comment: The refresh rate is not in your screen dumps.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Indeed, but I can attest that it is indeed 60Hz.

Comment: You may want to check https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328340/3157

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, I've seen before that it's 60Hz, from the System Profiler. But I don't have access to my 4K displays right now, so you'll have to take my word for it.